# Localization of Win32 Application without DLLs (VS2010)

Tags: winapi, localization, atl

I need to add the support for a number of languages for Win32 GUI application (ATL/WTL).

There are two restrictions:

1. Project is built using Visual Studio 2010 (no C++11 and also no MFC)
2. Result must be only ONE standalone *.exe (no additional files/DLLs)

The first and, actually, the only way I found (without DLLs) is to use STRINGTABLE in Resource-file, naming localizable strings like:

> ```
> WHAT_IS_YOUR_NAME_EN = ...
> WHAT_IS_YOUR_NAME_ES = ...
> WHAT_IS_YOUR_NAME_DE = ...
> etc...
> ```

And after, at the Application start, to detect current locale and to load correspondingly post-fixed strings from Resource STRINGTABLE (e.g., "*_DE")

But it looks ugly (no?) and difficult to maintain and to add new languages.

Please, help with alternative advice.
Thank you!

Comment: Standard resources support multiple languages (see [`FindResourceEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-findresourceexa) for example). You can use 3rd-party tools or the [Message Compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/message-compiler--mc-exe-) to produce the binary resources to link into the final executable.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you could try to use MUI. For more details, I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [Adding Multilingual User Interface Support to an Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/creating-a-multilingual-user-interface-application)

Comment: It's better to have DLLs. That's the way .NET does it and it's the conclusion I came to doing it with C++. The advantage of separate DLLs is 1) language DLLs for new translated locales can be added later, 2) only need to include the DLLs for the languages the user needs. IF you want to support a new language, you don't need to re-compile the program...just drop in the resource DLL.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson, but I have a strict requirement - only standalone executable without any satellite DLLs. Anyway, thank you. I always before this project used DLLs for this purpose.